# SQL Query Automation Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run a query to search for data in Microsoft Access and am running into a bit of a problem. The error occurs on the line

```
rec.Open sqlQuery, conn
```

and reads "Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Automation error"

```
Sub query21st()
    ' create file path reference string for 21st data
    dbPath = database_path()

    ' create connection string
    Dim connString As String
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & dbPath & ";" & _
    "Persist Security Info=False;"

    'create connection with connection string from above
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection 
    conn.Open connString

    ' create sql command string
    Dim lookupFields As String
    lookupFields = "cert.[avgle]"

    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "select " & lookupFields & " from [Certificates] as cert " & _
    "where [DOB] =" & [dob_21st] & " AND [CertificateDate] =" & [certdate_21st] & " AND [MPI1] =" & [mm] & ")"

    ' create recordset and get data from connection
    Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset
    rec.Open sqlQuery, conn

    [returnRange_21st].ClearContents
    [returnRange_21st].Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset rec


    ' close recordset
    rec.Close

    'close connection
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

The "database_path" function contains delicate info that cannot be posted but I guarantee it works just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print sqlQuery` show you?

Comment: You have a trailing closing parenthesis with no match.  Are all of your fields numeric?  If not then you may need to quote the query values